# JSP "оборачивается" в body

Tags: java, spring-boot

Всем привет! Использую spring boot + jsp. Не могу понять, почему jsp файл отдается просто как ресурс, и как это исправить(
Даже не знаю, что еще прикрепить...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Суть проблемы]

```
package com.gmail.nedoluga.yaroslav.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.gmail.nedoluga.yaroslav")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/").setCachePeriod(180);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/css/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/fonts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/img/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/img/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/js/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/js/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/pages/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите на первую строчку метода addResourceHandlers. Что, по-вашему, она делает?

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию Tomcat, который используется в Spring Boot, не поддерживает JSP (и разработчики не рекомендуют его использовать). Для того, чтобы включить поддержку JSP, необходимо добавить дополнительные зависимости в `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите строчку

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/").setCachePeriod(180);
```

Она инструктирует spring считать ваши jsp-шки статическими файлами.

Answer (score -1):

В начало .jsp файла добавьте:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению не сработало!:(