# Spring boot. Не обрабатывается JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Код контроллера:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "login.jsp";
    }
}
```

Вместо того, чтобы превратить эту страницу в html, он её просто возвращает как файл и браузер с помощью диалога сохранения предлагает её сохранить на компьютере.

Использую Spring Boot, все шаблонизаторы в духе Thymeleaf поотключал.

И заодно, что можно почитать на эту тему (Spring Boot и Java based config)? Потому что сейчас мне дико всё это выносит мозг, я откровенно не понимаю, почему если я просто подключил в зависимости Thymeleaf, он тут же начинает работать и искать View в папке resources/templates (почему эта папка, где это поменять?), если так, почему тогда для JSP файлы должны быть в папке webapp, а для других шаблонизаторов - нет?

Comment: Такой вопрос уже был: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583762/jsp-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-body 2)

Comment: Ага понял, спасибо ) Ну тогда пусть повисит пока ради второй части.

Comment: Я читал официальную документацию. Там есть практически всё.